# "no matching index found" when query using "filter" and "orderBy"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

**Problem**

I experience a *"no matching index found"* exception when querying a datastore for a property "imdbUrl" and sorting by property "created".

I defined the following entity in GAE-Datastore:

```
    // Create a Key factory to construct keys associated with this project.
    KeyFactory keyFactory = datastore.newKeyFactory().kind("FilmData");
    
    Key key = datastore.allocateId(keyFactory.newKey());
    Entity dataEntity = Entity.builder(key)
            .set("created", filmData.created)
            .set("name", StringValue.builder(filmData.name).indexed(true).build())
            .set("rating", DoubleValue.builder(UtilsConvert.toDouble(filmData.imdbRating)).indexed(true).build())
            .set("ratingCnt", UtilsConvert.toDouble(filmData.imdbRatingCnt))
            .set("imdbUrl", StringValue.builder(filmData.imdbUrl).indexed(true).build())
            .build();
```

Then I tried to retrieve the entities by running the following query:

```
    Filter imdbUrlFilter =  PropertyFilter.eq("imdbUrl", "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1431045/");
    
    Query<Entity> query = Query.entityQueryBuilder()
            .kind("FilmData")
            .filter(imdbUrlFilter)
            .orderBy(OrderBy.desc("created"))
            .build();

    Iterator<Entity> iterator = datastore.run(query);
```

I expected to retrieve the FilmData with the given "imdbUrl", sorted by "created".

Instead there is an exception:

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /rest/query/. Reason:
> no matching index found.
>
> Caused by:
> com.google.gcloud.datastore.DatastoreException: no matching index found.

Querying just for one single property works fine, but filtering and sorting - fails.

As described [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig) - I created an **index.yaml** and put it into my **WEB-INF** folder, to create a complex 2 property index. This did not help. The exception is still there.

Any ideas why?

```
indexes:

- kind: FilmData
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: imdbUrl
  - name: created
    direction: desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your index finished building before trying this code again. You can check index status in developer console (Datastore > Indexes).

Comment: And I should have deployed the app, so that the Datastore-server learns about the index.

Comment: Note `gcloud app deploy index.yaml` is needed. By itself `glcoud app deploy` doesn't include index.yaml, was quite frustrated trying to initially setup my index and found this annotation somewhere in the docs (apparently also true for cron.yaml and dispatch.yaml).